# binding связанных данных многие ко многим WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, many-to-many

Как биндить связанные данные многие ко многим 
к примеру:

```
public class Post
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public ICollection<PostTag> PostTags { get; } = new List<PostTag>();
}

public class Tag
{
    public int TagId { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public ICollection<PostTag> PostTags { get; } = new List<PostTag>();
}

public class PostTag
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public Post Post { get; set; }

    public int TagId { get; set; }
    public Tag Tag { get; set; }
}
```

Получение:

```
var Post_Tag =  db.Posts.Include(a=>a.PostTags).ThenInclude(a=>a.Tag).ToList();
Items= new ObservableCollection<Abonoment>();

Post_Tag .ForEach(Items.Add);

<ComboBox x:Name="Combo"
          DisplayMemberPath="Title"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"/>

<TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=Combo, Path=SelectedValue.PostTags.Tag.Text}" />
```

Как получить Text из Tag ?

Comment: Во-первых, почитайте как организовывать связь многие-ко-многим в EF. Вы не должны создавать промежуточную таблицу вручную, это должен сделать EF "за кулисами". Во-вторых, в выбранном Post целая коллекция Tag, когда вы пишете `SelectedValue.PostTags.Tag.Text`, то какой из Tag имеете ввиду? Первый? Последний? Десятый? Седьмой с конца?

Comment: @АндрейNOP, 1)связь я организовал по этому гайду https://blog.oneunicorn.com/2017/09/25/many-to-many-relationships-in-ef-core-2-0-part-1-the-basics/ 
2) он должен взять именно тот который связан по id с Post`ом

Comment: Хорошо, зайдем с другой стороны. PostTags это коллекция List, у коллекции есть свойство Tag? С Post может быть связано много Tag (и все по id).

Comment: @АндрейNOP,да,и что вы отите этим сказать ? я же беру именно выбранные элемент по SelectedItem , вы хотите сказать что по SelectedItem  он не возьмет связанные с ним данные ?

Comment: Рассмотрим связь многие-ко-многим между товаром и заказом. Пусть у нас есть Заказ №1 состоящий из товаров Товар1, Товар2 и Товар3 и есть Заказ №2 состоящий из товаров Товар2, Товар3, Товар5. Вы выводите список заказов, пользователь выбрал из списка Заказ №1. Вопрос, какой товар должен вывестись в SelectedValue.Товары.Наименование? Ведь в заказе не один товар, а **несколько**. И Товары - это коллекция товаров, у нее нету свойства Наименование. Для начала попробуйте переписать привязку так: `Path=SelectedValue.PostTags[0].Tag.Text`

Comment: @АндрейNOP,спасибо , так работает.  а это правильный путь ? или есть какой нибудь другой способ, и можете посоветовать какой нибудь ресурс для полного понимания?

Comment: Ну дык это и зависит от того, что вам нужно, я же у вас спрашивал: "какой из Tag имеете ввиду? Первый? Последний? Десятый? Седьмой с конца?" Вот сейчас отображается только первый Tag, но их же там может быть гораздо больше

Comment: @АндрейNOP, ну на пример десятый  это же уже будет `PostTags[9].Tag.Text`  верно ?

Comment: Да. Но я думаю, вам нужно же вывести все связанные теги? Тогда нужно соответственно не просто TextBlock, а ItemsControl и ему устанавливать уже ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedValue.PostTags}"

Comment: хорошо,а если например у каждого Post'a по одному Tag'у то в это случае как отобразить ?

Comment: Ну так как выше показано - через индексатор `[0]`

Comment: это при условии того что я точно знаю какой именно Tag мне нужен, и даже если   в связке 1 элемент только? другого способа нет ?